# Structure passing variables in another class

Tags: ios, struct, swift3

Basically, I am trying to build a music player app in order to learn iOS platform and Swift 3, but I am currently stuck on a simple step. I am trying to create an array of type song and append to that array the song names, after that song artist, etc.

The function also needs to be modified. I was using it before with a array of names, but after that I decided to create this struct.

```
import Foundation

struct Song {


    var _songTitle:String?

    var _songArtist:String?

    var _songDuration:Double?

    var _songCover:String?

}


import AVFoundation
```

class AudioManager: NSObject, AVAudioPlayerDelegate  {

```
static let sharedInstance = AudioManager()

var currentSong = 0

var currentTime = 0

var player: AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

private override init() {}


private var songs: [Song] = []

func play()
{

        player.play()
}

func stop() {
    if player.isPlaying{
     player.stop()
    }

}

func playThis()
{

    do
    {
        guard let audioPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: songs._songTitle?[currentSong], ofType: ".mp3")
            else {
                return

        }
        try player = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: audioPath) as URL)

    }
    catch
    {
        print ("ERROR")

    }


}


    func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool)
{

    if flag {
        currentSong += 1
    }

    if ((currentSong + 1) == songs.count) {
        currentSong = 0
    }


}

func skipForward() {
    var timeToSkip: TimeInterval = player.currentTime
    timeToSkip += 5.0
    player.currentTime = timeToSkip
}

func skipBack() {
    var timeToSkip: TimeInterval = player.currentTime
    timeToSkip -= 5.0
    player.currentTime = timeToSkip
}

func gettingSongNames()
{
    let folderURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:Bundle.main.resourcePath!)

    do
    {
        let songPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)

        //loop through the found urls
        for song in songPath
        {
            var mySong = song.absoluteString

            if mySong.contains(".mp3")
            {
                let findString = mySong.components(separatedBy: "/")
                mySong = findString[findString.count-1]
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: "%20", with: " ")
                mySong = mySong.replacingOccurrences(of: ".mp3", with: "")
                song._songTitle.append(mySong)

            }

        }


    }
    catch
    {
        print ("ERROR")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please include all relevant code in question and don't link it, especially not as a screenshot. Also, what is your question?

Comment: Follow a tutorial otherwise it'll be difficult for you.

Comment: dont get your issue im afraid.

Comment: So if this was a class i could access the variable name by class.variable and append the string there but with struct this is not working. How can i update the method so i can append the the songs array each string(song names)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are combining struct member access and array indexing in the wrong order. For example you have an array `song` of type `[Song]`, that is an array of songs, and to access a particular title you write:

```
songs._songTitle?[currentSong]
```

Which says "`songs` has an array-valued property `_songTitle`, access its `currentSong` element" - this is backwards. You need to access the array element first, which returns a `Song`, and then the property:

```
songs[currentSong]._songTitle
```

You also appear to wish to create a new song only specifying a title. To do this you shoul add an `init` method to `Song` along the lines of:

```
init(withTitle: String) { ... }
```

Which sets the title of the new song to the supplied value and the other properties to `nil`. (If you don't know about `init` methods look in Apple's Swift book.)

Once you have this initialiser adding a new song becomes something like:

```
songs.append( Song(withTitle:mySong) )
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method inside your `AudioManager` class instance to perform the addition of a song, like this:

```
func addSong(song: Song) {
    songs.append(song)
}
```

and you can use it like this:

```
let song = Song(_songTitle: "Title", _songArtist: "Artist", _songDuration: 0, _songCover: "Cover")
AudioManager.sharedInstance.addSong(song: song)
```

You can't do `song._songTitle.append(mySong)` since `_songTitle` is a string, not an array. You have to declare it as an array if you want to do an append.

Comment: So, if i understand this correctly i have to create a different array songName  in the audioManager class in which i append song. But how do i add the song name to the Song Struct Array without having to manually declare new instances of type Song.